# Include referenced project in nuget package

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget, .net-standard

I have a solution with 3 projects (using netstandard1.4). Project A contains shared code. Project B is a server side library and project C is a client side library. Project B and C include project A as project reference.

Now I want to publish project B and project C as a nuget package.

The Problem is the nuget packages for project B and C do not contain the code / dll from project A. It looks like project B and C want project A also as a nuget package.

**How can I pack the project B and C as standalone nuget packages?** I don’t want to publish project A as a nuget package.

Comment: Then when somebody install packages B and C would have A's code.

Comment: Why don't you want to publish A? the code would be usable anyway and if someone installs B and C it could cause conflicts.

Comment: Project A alone is usless and I don't tink there is any unsfull scenario to use B and C in the same project. A nuget packet for A makes it only more complicated for the user. 
Furthermore, what if I ever want to embed yet another project with shared code? 3 packages for one library do not seem very useful to me.

Answer (score 4):

> How can I pack the project B and C as standalone nuget packages? I don’t want to publish project A as a nuget package.

Since you are using `.NET Standard 1.4`, you could not use the direct way "`dotnet pack`" to include the project references. Because `dotnet pack` will pack only the project and not its P2P references, you can get the detail info from the document [dotnet-pack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-pack) and [the issue on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/3959):

> NuGet dependencies of the packed project are added to the .nuspec file, so they're properly resolved when the package is installed. Project-to-project references aren't packaged inside the project. Currently, you must have a package per project if you have project-to-project dependencies.

If you want to pack project B and C contain the code / dll from project A, you can use NuGet.exe to create the package B and C by adding project reference assemblies to the .nuspec file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>TestProjectB</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <authors>Tester</authors>
    <owners>Tester</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Package description</description>
    <releaseNotes>Test sample for netstandard package.</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2017</copyright>
    <tags>Tag1 Tag2</tags>
  </metadata>
<files>
    <file src="bin\Debug\netstandard1.4\TestProjectB.dll" target="lib\netstandard1.4\TestProjectB.dll" />
    <file src="bin\Debug\netstandard1.4\TestProjectA.dll" target="lib\netstandard1.4\TestProjectA.dll" />
</files>
</package>
```

In this case, you can pack the project B and C as standalone nuget packages, do not need publish project A as a nuget package.